Nonlinear Optimization of Noisy Functions w/ Bound Constraints via SciPy
Can we use scipy.optimize.minimize to find the best parameters $\mathbf{w} \in \Omega^k$,
$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$, of a function
$g = g(f(\mathbf{x}), \mathbf{w})$ depending on other, black-box function $f$ if we have
only noisy observations $\tilde{f}_i = \tilde{f}(x_i)$, $i=1,\dots,n$? We don't have exact
$f$ (and so $\nabla f$ and $\mathbf{H}_f$) to use, e.g., minimize(method='trust-constr').
But when I run, say,
minimize(g, method='trust-constr', bounds=w_bounds, args=X)

scipy somehow manages to find solutions albeit not the best ones compared to simple greedy search. Does any method in minimize really support this case?
P.S. If you need an example use-case: $f$ - machine learning algorithm,
$g$ - scoring function, $\mathbf{w}$ - hyperparameters of some meta-learner on $f$,
$\mathbf{X} = (\mathbf{x}_i, y_i)_{i=1}^k$ - (validation/test) dataset. For now, I'm not
considering common hyperparameter-optimization methods like the ones from optuna.
